# Table Border property not showing up in google chrome version 61 for mac

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I made a table in html and tried to apply styles to it using css but the output is not showing up in google chrome version 61 for mac.

I don't know what is wrong but the border is not showing up only.

I am using Macos Sierra.

The editor that I am using is Brackets.

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Harsh Parikh</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table{
          border:3px solid red;
         }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>

    <tr>
    <td>Board</td>
    <td>Stream</td>
    <td>Percentage</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>SSC</td>
    <td>Regular</td>
    <td>86%</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>HSC</td>
    <td>Science</td>
    <td>63%</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Engineering</td>
    <td>Who Cares?</td>
    <td>Brain Damager</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>BMM</td>
          <td>Advertising</td>
          <td>A Grade</td>
          </tr>



  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try this in Chrome the code seems to work (produces a single red border around the table). However, try changing your doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` rather than the transitional doctype. Also try breaking the style declaration into individual properties, for example;

```
table {
border-width:3px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:red;
}
```